# insert mode Gcommit fugitive

Tags: git, vim, insert, commit, vim-fugitive

I am trying to commit using *:Gcommit*. A split window appears. I think I am supposed to enter the commit message there. However, when I press "i" to enter the insert mode, the buffer changes and I see lines, which are looking like the follwing one.

```
100644 f4ae5fb126cf3316410e05d113802464791b3813 0   filename
```

When I press "i" again, I am back to the window where I would like to enter the commit message.

**Question:** How do I enter the insert mode in this situation in order to enter the commit message?

(I am using vim-fugitive commit d854197c03c0b027cca41abf86a5557c5473b82f.)

Comment: You probably don't have anything staged.

Comment: Excellent question, thank you for asking this.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Simply put, you want:

```
:Gcommit -a
```

Like me, you probably always skip staging individual files when you enter your commits and simply commit all changes at once with the command:

```
$ git commit -a
```

That's why using

```
:Gcommit
```

alone isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the window where you type your commit message. Since you have not staged anything, fugitive calls `:Gstatus` instead to show the index. Typing `i` in this window brings you to another view of the index. You should type `i` again to go back to the standard view, `-` to add files to the index, then commit with `:Gcommit` (then you will be able to type your commit message).

These commands are documented in `:help fugitive-:Gcommit` and `:help fugitive-:Gstatus`.

Comment: [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episodes: [The Fugitive Series - a retrospective](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/)